# Yii import conditions

Tags: yii

```
models. * 
classes. *
```

How do not import some files of the directories? And import them only when we need?

For example: I need import file models/SomeModel.php only in controller SomeController.php. I need import file classes/SomeClass.php only in controller SomeController.php and Some2Controller.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use when needed:

```
Yii::import('application.models.SomeModel');// protected/models/SomeModel.php
Yii::import('application.classes.SomeClass');//  protected/classes/SomeClass.php
```

But beware that `import()` is different than `require` or `include`, import relies on Class names being the same as file names.

Comment: is the file name that was included, the same name as class?

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?